# Using a ListAdapter to show database data

Tags: android, database, listview

```
public class List_View extends ListActivity {

    private TextView toptext; 
    private TextView bottomtext;

    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);
        getData();

        toptext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toptext); 
        bottomtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bottomtext); 

    }

    private void getData() {            
           db.open();

           Cursor c = db.getAllEntry();
           c.moveToFirst(); 

           ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.view_list, c, new String[] {"date", "title"}, new int[] {R.id.toptext, R.id.bottomtext});

           bottomtext.setText(c.getString(1)); 
           toptext.setText(c.getString(4)); 

           setListAdapter(adapter);

           db.close(); 
    }

}
```

I would like to show stored data from database into a ListView.

Title and Date only.

Comment: Please consider taking the time to run your eyes over the other questions here. None are written all in capitals, or require the word "help" - it's a Q&A site, hence "help" is redundant. Also, using phrases like "URGENT :(" won't help you get assistance any quicker

Comment: ... and then, please tell us what your problem exactly is. You seem to have already a piece of code, which unfortunately doesn't work. So explain what the code is trying to do and what the actual outcome is. By the way: Questions here are almost *always* answered very quickly, *if* you take time to formulate your question so that the readers understand it immediately.

Comment: Because I'm really freaking desperate for the answer. & the problem is that I just can't seem to show my data from the database in the listview that i want!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Stored Data from my Database into ListView. ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090041/getting-stored-data-from-my-database-into-listview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just glancing over it; your call to getData lies before toptext and bottomtext is set.