# Android tabluar data from database

Tags: android, database, tabular

I want to show all the data from the database in a View. `addview` to the layout is a good idea. But as I don't know the no. of data, I cann't create required no. of textview, and i cann't add a single textview multiple number of time. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But as I don't know the no. of data, I cann't create required no. of textview, and i cann't add a single textview multiple number of time.

You don't need to create `TextView` multiple times, it would lead to more complex application.
Rather I would suggest you shold create a simple or custom `ListView` using simple or custom `ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter or CursorAdapter`accordingly your needs.

Refer this: [Getting Stored Data from my Database into ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090041/getting-stored-data-from-my-database-into-listview)

Answer (score 0):

Just read this article to learn how to get info from the database using CRUD methodology:
http://knightswhocode.com/wordpress/?p=14
Create a list of items taken from the database. Then create a ListView with adapter using this list.