# How can i maintain sq-lite data. When user clears data from application Manager

Tags: android, sqlite

In my android app i use SQLite database for storing and retrieving data.

When user clear the data from application manager the data will be cleared.But my requirement is when user clear's data from application manager my data will be *static* it doesn't remove.

How can i manage that database?

Please provide any solutions.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: "But my requirement is when user clear's data from application manager my data will be static it doesn't remove" -- fortunately, users can always delete whatever data they want.

Comment: Here I need to maintain data when offline so I need above requirement

Comment: @user1750076 So basically you're saying your users will clear out the data while offline and still expect it to be there?

Comment: Yes exactly.If users clear the data without accessing the server I need to display the data(in offline mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users can clear data if they want. So you can not make your database static.
But, If you want to keep your database, you can copy your database to assets folder and when app invoke method `onCreate` of SQLiteHelper, you will copy from assets folder to device.

Here is the sample:

**DBHelper**

```
package vn.mve.db;

import java.util.List;

public interface DBHelper<T> {
    boolean insert(T val);
    boolean update(T val);
    boolean delete(T val);
    List<T> getList(int type);
    T getChild(Object val);
}
```

**DBHandler**

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String TAG = DBHandler.class.getSimpleName();
    protected SQLiteDatabase db; 
    private final Context context;  
    private static String PACKAGE_NAME = "";
    private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, Def.DBNAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context; 
        PACKAGE_NAME = this.context.getPackageName();
        Def.FOLDER_DB = "/data/data/" + PACKAGE_NAME + "/databases/";
        Log.d(TAG, Def.FOLDER_DB);
        try {
            this.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            this.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        context.deleteDatabase(Def.DBNAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
        // for first database;
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if(!dbExist){
            try {
                copyDataBase("db/" + Def.DBNAME);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "createDatabse -> Copy failed!");
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        } else {
            open();
            boolean isExist = false;
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = 'config'", null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                isExist = true;
                cursor.close();
            } else {
                isExist = false;
            }
            close();
            Log.d(TAG, isExist + "");
            if (!isExist) {
                this.context.deleteDatabase(Def.DBNAME);
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "createDatabase when database has existed");
                    copyDataBase(Def.DBNAME);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "createDatabse -> Copy failed!");
                    throw new Error("Error copying database");
                }               
            }
        }
    }   
    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase(String DB) {
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = null;
        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = null;
        try {
            myInput = context.getResources().getAssets().open(DB);

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = Def.FOLDER_DB + Def.DBNAME; 
            myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0){
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "copyDatabase -> File not found.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "copyDatabase");
        } finally {
              //Close the streams
            try {
                myOutput.flush();
                myOutput.close();
                myInput.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }   
    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        boolean checkDB = false;
        try{
            String myPath = Def.FOLDER_DB + Def.DBNAME;
            File dbFile = new File(myPath); 
            checkDB = dbFile.isFile();
            Log.d(TAG, "checkDatabase: " + String.valueOf(checkDB));
            try {
                File fTmp = new File(Def.FOLDER_DB);
                if (!fTmp.exists()) {
                    fTmp.mkdir();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "checkDatabase" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }catch(SQLiteException e){}
        return checkDB;
    }
    public void open() {
        try {
            String myPath = Def.FOLDER_DB + Def.DBNAME;
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);          
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
            if(db != null)
                db.close();
            super.close();
    }           
    public SQLiteDatabase getSqlDb() {
        return db;
    }
    public void setSqlDb(SQLiteDatabase sqlDb) {
        this.db = sqlDb;
    }    
}
```

And here:

```
public class MVideo extends DBHandler implements DBHelper<Video> {
    public static final String TAG = MVideo.class.getSimpleName();
    public MVideo(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean insert(Video val) {
        open();
        ContentValues cValues = new ContentValues();
        cValues.put(Def.Video.ID, val.getId());
        cValues.put(Def.Video.TITLE, val.getTitle());
        cValues.put(Def.Video.THUMBNAIL, val.getThumbnail());
        cValues.put(Def.Video.DESCRIPTION, val.getDescription());
        cValues.put(Def.Video.ENGLISH, val.getEnglish());
        cValues.put(Def.Video.VIETNAMESE, val.getVietnamese());
        cValues.put(Def.Video.ISVIEW, val.getIsView());
        long result = db.insert(Def.Video.NAME, null, cValues);
        close();        
        return result > 0;
    }

    public boolean insertList(List<Video> list) {
        open();
        db.execSQL("BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION");
        for (Video v : list) {
            db.execSQL(String.format("INSERT INTO " + Def.Video.NAME + " (\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\") VALUES" + 
                    " (\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\")",
                    Def.Video.ID, Def.Video.TITLE, Def.Video.THUMBNAIL, Def.Video.DESCRIPTION, 
                    Def.Video.ENGLISH, Def.Video.VIETNAMESE, Def.Video.ISVIEW,
                    v.getId(), v.getTitle(), v.getThumbnail(), v.getDescription(), v.getEnglish(), v.getVietnamese(), v.getIsView() + ""));
            Log.d(TAG, "insertList -> " + v.toString());
        }
        db.execSQL("COMMIT TRANSACTION");
        close();        
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean update(Video val) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(Video val) {
        open();
        db.delete(Def.Video.NAME, Def.Video.ID + "=?", new String[]{val.getId()});
        close();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Video> getList(int type) {
        List<Video> list = new ArrayList<Video>();
        open();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(Def.Video.GET_ALL, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                String ID = c.getString(0);
                String title = c.getString(1);
                String thumbnail = c.getString(2);
                String description = c.getString(3);
                String english = c.getString(4);
                String vietnamese = c.getString(5);
                boolean isView = Boolean.parseBoolean(c.getString(6));
                list.add(new Video(ID, title, thumbnail, description, english, vietnamese, isView));
            }
        }
        close();
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public Video getChild(Object val) {
        open();
        Cursor c = db.query(Def.Video.NAME, new String[]{
                Def.Video.ID, Def.Video.TITLE, Def.Video.THUMBNAIL, Def.Video.DESCRIPTION, 
                Def.Video.ENGLISH, Def.Video.VIETNAMESE, Def.Video.ISVIEW
        }, Def.Video.ID + "=?", new String[]{val.toString()}, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        Video v = new Video(c.getString(0), c.getString(1), 
                c.getString(2), c.getString(3), c.getString(4), 
                c.getString(5), Boolean.parseBoolean(c.getString(6)));
        close();
        return v;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The user is always free to remove application data, otherwise any application could fill up the phone, refuse to uninstall and require a factory reset to clean up.

If you really need the data safely stored, back it up to the cloud and restore it when the user reinstalls the application.

Answer (score 0):

The database is the place to keep your data for offline usage.

The only possibility I know would be to create a backup of the database on the SDCard in a directory of your choice. This folder will not be deleted when the user clears the data from the application manager. The downside of this "solution" would be that you need to implement the logic about recovering the backup. Also your backup will survive any deinstallation and new installations and I doubt that you want to restore a database from a previous installation.

To make it short: This would be a possible way to go but it has a lot of pitfalls and isn't really recommended. Let the user keep the control over the application and keep in mind: the user once figured out that you have a backup on the sdcard, he will eventually delete it, too.